# Excel IF statement based on what language excel is sat to, how do i get it to work?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So im using excel to query some data, and based on what language the excel workbook is set to I use this formula.

```
=IF(INTRO!E6="English";CONCATENATE("'";TEXT(J8;"YYYY-MM-dd");"'");IF(INTRO!E6="Swedish";CONCATENATE("'";TEXT(J8;"ÅÅÅÅ-MM-dd");"NA");"NA"))
```

When I run it I get the message : unterminated quoted string at or near "2020-07-31NA)";

this is what happens in the vba code to query our pgadmin /postgresql database :

```
"SELECT * FROM logic.exposure_split(" & datestring & ")"
```

and the intro!e6 is where the user choose what language of excel they have.

Comment: @JohnColeman please see the updated version of the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your formula:

```
=IF(
    INTRO!E6="English";
    CONCATENATE(
        "'";
        TEXT(J8;"YYYY-MM-dd");
        "'"
    );
    IF(
        INTRO!E6="Swedish";
        CONCATENATE(
            "'";
            TEXT(J8;"ÅÅÅÅ-MM-dd");
            "NA"
        );
        "NA"
)   )
```

If J8 is January 2nd, 2021 then

- In English, your formula returns `'2021-01-02'`
- If Swedish, your formula returns `'2021-01-02NA` with no ending single-quote.

Comment: sorry *postgresql* 
But is that why? I'll try changing but I doubt that will fix it.

Comment: Yes. Your datestring variable is computing to `'something` when it needs to be `'something'`

Comment: uhm, so : "SELECT * FROM logic.exposure_split('"  & datestring & "')"
?

Comment: no... see how in the English version, your Concatenate has 3 args, but the Swedish only has 2? You're missing the 3rd argument of `"'"`

Comment: wait... I'm wrong.. it's worse than that. Let me change my answer...

Answer (score 0):

correct code should me:

```
=IF(INTRO!E6="English";CONCATENATE("'";TEXT(J8;"yyyy-mm-dd");"'");IF(INTRO!E6="Swedish";CONCATENATE("'";TEXT(J8;"ÅÅÅÅ-MM-DD");"'")))
```